# jQuery easyui datebox event to querying mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-easyui, datebox

I use this script on jQuery easyui datebox

```
<script> 
        function onSelect(date){ 
            $('#result').text(date)       
        } 

</script>
```

and the output is

```
Selected Date: Tue Jun 11 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time)
```

so, is it possible to make the output :

```
2013-06-11
```

how to make it?

Because I want to pass the value datebox event in to querying mysql

getdata.php

```
<?php
include 'db.php';

   $created = isset($_POST['text']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['text']) : '';

$where = "datetime LIKE '$created%'";
$rs = mysql_query("select * from fe1a where " . $where );

$result = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($rs)){
    array_push($array, $row);
}


echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/xV9BZ/

#### Javascript:

```
$('.easyui-datebox').datebox({
    onSelect: function(date){
        alert(date.getFullYear()+"-"+(date.getMonth()+1)+"-"+date.getDate());
    }
});
```

or in your case would be:

```
$('.easyui-datebox').datebox({
    onSelect: function(date){
        $('#result').text(date.getFullYear()+"-"+(date.getMonth()+1)+"-"+date.getDate());
    }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/default/easyui.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <input class="easyui-datebox"></input>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
function onSelect(date){ 
                $('#result').text(date.getFullYear() + '-' + date.getMonth() + '-' + date.getDate());       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the format in php with *strftime()* and *strtotime()*:

```
$created = isset($_POST['text']) ? strftime('%Y-%m-%d', strtotime(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['text']))) : '';
```

Comment: The use of Date-object dit the tric.
`$date = new DateTime($_POST['text']); 
$date = $date->format(Y-m-d');`

Answer (score 0):

Example http://jsfiddle.net/vwhy1fnm/1/

## Javascript:

Use this for output (2015-01-01).

```
var result;
$('.easyui-datebox').datebox({
    onSelect: function (date) {
        var y = date.getFullYear();
        var m = date.getMonth() + 1;
        var d = date.getDate();
        result = (y + '-' + (m < 10 ? ('0' + m) : m) + '-' + (d < 10 ? ('0' + d) : d));
        alert(result);//<--alert for example you can remove this
    }
});
```

## HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/default/easyui.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <input class="easyui-datebox"></input>  
    </body>
</html>
```